# Get more then 250 results from a Google Play store query

Tags: android, google-play

A query to the Google Play Store (e.g. http://play.google.com/store/search?q=maps&c=apps) gives a maxium of 250 results. If 250 apps are shown, the "Show more" button doesn't appear any more and scrolling down will also not show more results.

But how can i get more then 250 results for a query?
I want to perform data mining on app meta data for a scientific project and for this i would need ALL results.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is currently no official Google Play Search API. So you might want to try a few unofficial ones, e.g. https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ as well as Google Play Store crawlers: https://github.com/chadrem/market_bot, https://github.com/MarcelloLins/GooglePlayAppsCrawler.

There are also commercial solutions, e.g. https://42matters.com/api/search.

Comment: I tried the free ones (and some more, e.g. https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api) and like my personal crawler, they also suffer from the limited amount of results returned by Google's server. My problem is the limited amout of results, not automation. Does the commercial solution not have this limitation?